# how to load .bashrc environment variables in python 2.7 IDLE at startup

Tags: python, ubuntu

I would like to have the environment variables i defined in my .bashrc to be loaded in python 2.7 IDLE on starting it from the ubuntu launcher.

These environment variables are loaded correctly when i start IDLE from the command line.

One solution http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=253555&p=1484153#post1484153 modifies the /usr/bin/idle-python2.7 to include an environment variable at idle startup.

I am not sure how to do this for all environment variables without having to parse the .bashrc file in python.

Specifically, i want to export a variable in my .bashrc

```
export FOO="BAR"
```

and i wish to open idle-python2.7 from the ubuntu launcher and type:

```
>>> import os
>>> print os.environ['FOO']
BAR
```

**Software Details:**

```
OS: Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit
python version: 2.7
```

Please let me know if you require additional information from my part.

Answer (score 0):

Two ideas from the [manual](http://docs.python.org/2/library/idle.html#startup).

1. Change the ubuntu launcher to run `idle.py -s` and set an environment variable `IDLESTARTUP` pointing to a file containing python commands to set your env.
2. Create an `.Idle.py` in `~/` file that does the same thing (but triggered by `Tkinter`)

Neither of those will execute `.bashrc` so another idea

- Create a custom ubuntu launcher that sources your `.bashrc` and then
  fires up `IDLE`

and my favourite

- Just use `ipython` or regular `python` from the shell, `IDLE` isn't that great :)

Comment: I had looked at the idle-python2.7 manual earlier, but could not figure out how to export the environment variables in .bashrc without writing code to parse it in python

Comment: I had earlier tried sourcing the bashrc and then executing idle-python2.7. The launcher would not load the modified idle-python2.7 at all. I could not figure out why. Here is what i did earlier:

    sudo mv /usr/bin/idle-python2.7 /usr/bin/idle-python2.7.original
    sudo vi /usr/bin/idle-python2.7
    
The contents of /usr/bin/idle-python2.7 were modified to:
    source /home/username/.bashrc && /usr/bin/idle-python2.7.original

I then gave execute permissions

    sudo chmod a+x /usr/bin/idle-python2.7

Do you have any idea as to why the launcher would not load? What was i doing incorrectly

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but the launcher file /usr/share/app-install/desktop/idle-python2.7:idle-python2.7.desktop executes idle-python2.7 as follows:

    Exec=/usr/bin/idle-python2.7 -n